# How to use cellEditEnding or current cell changed event in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services

I'am new to WPF and getting following error how to reslove this.I want to show warning message after editing the grid row and proceeding with next action without saving grid record. how to create an event in MVVM?

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'File' does not contain a definition for 'cellEditEnding' and no extension method 'cellEditEnding' accepting a first argument of type 'File' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 <DataGrid   x:Name="DataGrid" utils:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=txtText, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   CellEditEnding="dataGrid_CellEditEnding" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollectionView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="5" SelectionMode="Single" RowStyle="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedVoice, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                    CanUserAddRows="False" Tag="{Binding Path=HasError,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    CanUserResizeRows="True" >
```

---

```
private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender,
                                      DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView rowView = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
        rowBeingEdited = rowView;
    }
```

Comment: How long have you been doing programming ? Replace `cellEditEnding` with `dataGrid_CellEditEnding` in xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have solved it as below:

In Xaml

```
   <DataGrid   x:Name="DataGrid" utils:DataGridTextSearch.SearchValue="{Binding ElementName=txtText, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CollectionView}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="5" SelectionMode="Single" RowStyle="{StaticResource DefaultRowStyle}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedVoice, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserSortColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                CanUserAddRows="False" Tag="{Binding Path=HasError,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                CanUserResizeRows="True" >

         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CellEditCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </DataGrid>
```

In ViewModel.cs

```
    private RelayCommand cellEditingCommand;
    public ICommand CellEditCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (cellEditingCommand == null)
            {
                cellEditingCommand = new RelayCommand(CellEdit, CanCellEdit);
            }
            return cellEditingCommand;
        }
    }

    private bool CanCellEdit(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void CellEdit(object parameter)
    {
        Pool.isEdit = true;
    }
```